# Dynamic Constructor using Lambda and Func<>

Tags: c#, linq, design-patterns, func

I have a multithreaded app that is creating a list of strings on a BlockingCollection queue, I want to take that list of strings and convert it to a collection of item objects in one or 2 steps

Is it possible to create a func<> or lamda method to achieve this type of result

```
 public class item
{
    public string name { get; set; }

    public item(string nam)
    {
        name = nam;
    }


}

IList<string> alist = new string[] {  "bob","mary"};
```

Where you take a Ilist<> or IEnumerable<> of type string and return IList

So for the single item Func<>

```
Func<string, item> func1 = x => new item(x);
```

But essetially the signiture would look like

```
Func<IEnumerable<string>,IList<item>> func2 = x=> x.ForEach(i => func1(i));
```

Am I trying to put a round peg in sqaure hole or is my syntax/logic just wrong

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will have to use a  `Select` projection instead of `ForEach` and then convert the resulting `IEnumerable<item>` to a list using `ToList()`  - this should work:

```
Func<IEnumerable<string>,IList<item>> func2 = x => x.Select( i => new item(i)).ToList();
```

Comment: This answer was most applicable to my question even though I was over cooking the problem

Answer (score 5):

Are you just trying to "reshape" the `IList<string>` as `IList<item>`?

```
IList<string> listOfStrings = new string[] {  "bob","mary"};
IList<item> listOfItems = listOfStrings.Select(s => new item(s)).ToList();
```

Comment: Yours is the more elegant solution

Answer (score 3):

```
IEnumerable<item> myfunc(IEnumerable<string> stringlist)
{
    var q = from s in stringlist
            select new item(s);
    return q.ToList();
}
```

Comment: Why call `ToList()`, then effectively cast back to `IEnumerable<T>`?  Just return q directly...

Comment: @ReedCopsey Returning q directly runs the risk of constructing the item objects multiple times if the function result is iterated multiple times by the caller.  Memory hog.  ToList() ensures there's only one iteration, one set of instantiations regardless of how the caller uses the function result.